# Magento 2.3 no files in folder after installation

Tags: magento2

No files into installation folder after web installation.

I'm trying to install **Magento 2.3 on Aruba hosting**  so to avoid the sql permission denied **I disabled checkDatabaseName and checkDatabasePrivileges** checks in `setup\src\Magento\Setup\Validator\DbValidator.php` (line number 106). 
The **php version installed is 7.2.13.** 
The Readiness check is successful and the installation ended without errors after all the steps, the database has been created without issues and I can see the tables into it.

The installation folder is empty and when I try to restart the setup the message is "Welcome to Magento Admin, your online store headquarters.
To use the Magento setup wizard sign into your Admin account and navigate to **System => Tools => Web Setup Wizard".**

No errors found into install.log and debug.log. 
I could retry to install using command line but I need to understand why this happen?